# Hyperledger-composer unable to change BlockTimeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working on prototyping a game using hyperledger-composer. I need to decrease the block time out however the instructions provided in the fabric-dev-servers do not work.

I followed the `howtobuild.txt` found in `~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer` however installing the network using `composer network start --networkName ....` the network fails to start with the error:

`Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event`

the versions i am uising are `composer@20` and fabric docker images with the tag `1.2.1` (as downloaded by) `./startFabric.sh`

The steps I have taken are exactly as follows:

```
cd ~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer

nano configtx.yaml
```

inside this file I

1. Move the profile block to the bottom of the ymal (to stop the weird error)
2. change BatchTimeout to 200ms
3. changed MaxMessageCount to 1

after saving the file I do

```
rm -r crypto-config

cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

get the new key and update `docker-composer.yml` and `docker-compose-dev.yml`

```
$(ls -1 crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/*_sk`
```

get key from keystore

```
 ls -1 crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/*_sk
```

update peerAdminCard sell script with the new key

```
nano ../createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Generate

```
configtxgen -profile ComposerChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./composer-channel.tx -channelID composerchannel`

configtxgen -profile ComposerOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./composer-genesis.block
```

create peer admin card

```
cd ../ && ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

At this point it starts downloading the fabric docker images, which all run successfully

I then create my BNA file and try to start the network

```
cd /my/buisness/network
composer archive create -t dir -n .
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile my-game@0.0.1.bna
composer network start --networkName my-game --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

which gives the error

```
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event
```

**The Debugging steps i have taken are as follows**

After viewing the peer logs i can see delivering blocks to the orderer fails because `composerchannel` does not exist, so i manually try to create and join the channel manually

```
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx
```

which is a success

```
2019-03-23 00:07:38.131 UTC [cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 05e Received block: 0
```

I then try to join the peer to the channel

```
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -o orderer.example.com:7050 -b composerchannel.block --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --keyfile /etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key --certfile /etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt
```

which gives the error

```
proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: access denied for [JoinChain][composerchannel]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]])
```

There are a lot of different 'Admin' Pems inside the `/etc/hyperledger/msp` and `/etc/hyperledger/tls` so I'm pretty much trying all combinations

I'm at a loss, I've been on google for hours trying to find anyone with the same issue but have come up short. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

---

Turns out explicitly defining the certificates where not needed. running this command allowed me to join the channel.

```
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -o orderer.example.com:7050 -b composerchannel.block  --clientauth --tls
```

at this point all the docker containers were running and the channel was working. i manage to be able to start the network and everything ran fine (i could request the chaincode, ledger was updating fine etc). However it still seems to take 2 seconds to process a transaction. Again i did some debugging to make sure the config on the order was correct.

1. fetch config block from channel on orderer

```
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o http_s_://orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
```

2. copy out of container to local machine

```
docker cp 5eeaf8c650f8:/root/config_block.pb config_block.pb
```

3. convert from proto-buf to json (using configtxlator binary found in fabric-samples)
   `configtxlator docker exec peer0.org1.example.com proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config > config.json`

After getting the config of the channel i could see that the BatchTimeout was 200ms and BatchAmount was 1, yet i still have the 2 seconds timeout per transaction.

Answer (score 0):

While working with Hyperledger composer now you have to keep in mind that it is obselete. I have followed these same steps many times in the past and built custom networks. I think your issue could be of version mismatch. Try downgrading composer to 0.19.

Additionally, did you try doing a docker ps to make sure that all the required containers are running?

Also, before doing the configtxgen command there's a simple command

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
```

Did you do this?

Comment: When you have built your custom networks in the past was it using v0.19 and follow these exact steps? I actually managed to solve this issue, however, even though the config updated. the network still seemed to process transactions in 2 second batches (i will update my question above encase anyone else has this issue). I did some basic benchmarking (time function takes that calls to blockchain and return data) and it was always still 2 seconds(i wait for the block to be ordered and committed, i do not use events as this a card game that relies on ledger being updated before game state updated)

Comment: Appreciate the help man, i am aware they stoped developing composer so didn't expect to get any help. Your my last hope before i scrap composer and all my BNA code and write actual chaincode (which id rather not do as this is a prototype)